# Configuration status sent to WARN but still getting DEBUG messages in console

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I have my configuration status set to "WARN" but I still get a bunch of debugging lines in my console..

This is my log4j2.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

But I'm still getting things like this

```
10:33:38.154 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-1 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
10:33:38.154 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-1 >> "POST /regexui/request HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
10:33:38.154 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-1 >> "Content-type: application/json[\r][\n]"
```

Comment: This works fine for me. Is your configuration file on the classpath? Are you sure your app isn't picking up some other configuration?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's picking up this file...when I delete the file it complains that it cant find it.